# Parse csv using "csv-parser" node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, csv, csv-parser

I am using the 'csv-parser' library.
Using the method below I am able to get the data stored in the birthdays array shown in the console:

```
    const birthdays = [];  
fs.createReadStream('./data/groupes.csv')
        .pipe(csv({}))
        .on('data', (data) => birthdays.push(data))
        .on('end', () => {
          console.log(birthdays)
      });
```

but when I log outside the `.on('end')` like below, the console shows the birthdays array as empty:

```
    const birthdays = [];  
fs.createReadStream('./data/groupes.csv')
        .pipe(csv({}))
        .on('data', (data) => birthdays.push(data))
        .on('end', () => {
      });
      console.log(birthdays)
```

Why is that? and how can I solve it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is that?

It's because createReadStream is working asynchronously and when you `console.log(birthdays);` outside, the code execution reads the log before createReadStream has finished processing

> how can I solve it?

You were correct to put it inside the .on("end")

```
const birthdays = [];  
fs.createReadStream('./data/groupes.csv')
    .pipe(csv({}))
    .on('data', (data) => birthdays.push(data))
    .on('end', () => {
      console.log(birthdays);
      // further processing with birthdays
  });
```

Comment: As a follow up question, I am trying to assign a value of a variable already declared inside the .on('end') part but it doesn't work for some reason, any idea why?

Comment: @Mehdi I would be able to help if you could share how you are declaring the variable and what exactly isn't working (eg, if there is an error)

Comment: I have posted another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72099168/csv-parser-onend-nodejs
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something like this?

```
const csv = require("csv-parser");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const { promisify } = require("util");
const readFile = promisify(fs.readFile);

const birthdays = [];

const filePath = path.join(__dirname, "data", "groupes.csv");

readFile(filePath, "utf8").then((data) => {
  csv(data, {
    separator: ",",
  })
    .on("data", (row) => {
      birthdays.push(row);
    })
    .on("end", () => {
      console.log(birthdays);
    });
});
```